# skip whitespaces but not newline in c without break and continue

Tags: c, arrays

I want to read characters from user and assign the chars to char array. But I want to skip whitespaces except `\n`(newline char). The loop would be end when press `\n`. How can I do it ? I cannot use `break` and `continue`. Thank you for all appreciated answers.

```
char *
get_set(char *set) 
{
      char inset[10];
      char ch = ' ';
      int i = 0;

      while(ch != '\n'){
          inset[i] = scanf(" %c", &ch);
          i++;
      }
      set[strlen(inset)] = '\0';
      return (set);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [getchar](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar):

```
while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n')) {
    if(!isspace(ch))
         inset[i++] = ch;
}
```

getchar reads the next character from stdin and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

Comment: could you explain the code ? why `EOF` ? Also, I think It doesn't work.

Comment: I applied your idea on my code but It doesn't work. So, I can enter  values limitless

Comment: @Soner, sure it's needed. If there is no newline in the input, you'll hang in an infinite loop. I strongly advise you to read the documentation of the functions you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *get_set(int size, char *set){// size : size of set as buffer size
    char ch;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size-1 && (ch=getchar()) != '\n'; ){
        if(!isspace(ch))
            set[i++] = ch;
    }
    set[i] = '\0';
    return set;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry. It can work but I cannot use `continue` as well.

Answer (score -1):

once try these,
    char *

```
get_set(char *set) 
{
  char inset[SETSIZ];
  char ch = ' ';
  int i = 0;

  while(ch != '\n'){
  if(ch!=32)// ASCII 32 for whitespaces
  inset[i] = scanf(" %c", &ch);
  i++;
  }
  set[strlen(inset)] = '\0';
  return (set);
  }
```

Comment: I cannot put a value because of  `if(ch!=32)`

Comment: if whitespace cames in between the words then its not ask scan line code then you can avoid it....in that way i was thinking.